# Evaluating a Double Integral Involving Fractional Part Functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral, fractional-part

> In my project, I am stuck with the following integral. Please help.
> $$  I = \int_{x = a}^b \int_{y = a}^b \left\{ \frac xy\right\} \left\{\frac >yx\right\}~dx~dy$$ $0 < a < b < 1, b < 2a$, where $\lbrace \rbrace$ is the fractional part function.

I found an approximation of the integral calculated on the square $(0,\alpha)^2, \alpha < 1$ on your forum. I tried using the known values of the integral on the squares $(0,a)^2, (0,b)^2$ in calculation of the integral in discussion. Let $f(x,y)=\left\{ \frac xy\right\} \left\{\frac yx\right\}$, then
$$\int_{x = a}^b \int_{y = a}^b  f(x,y)~dx~dy = \int_{x = 0}^b \int_{y = 0}^b  f(x,y)~dx~dy-  \int_{x = 0}^a \int_{y = 0}^a  f(x,y)~dx~dy - 2   \int_{x = 0}^b \int_{y = 0}^a  f(x,y)~dx~dy$$

I get stuck trying to follow the idea used in calculation of the integrals on the squares $(0,a)^2$ and $(0,b)^2$ in calculation of the last one. Even taking $b = 2a$ was not useful.

I hope I'll have the chance to receive a response.

Thank you in advance.

Al

Comment: Hi user. What have you tried, if anything? If you share this by Editing above, people here won't need to show you things you already know. You should also review the following, since you are new here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959

Comment: I tried using the known values of the integral on the squares (0,a)$^2$, (0,b)$^2$ in calculus of the integral in discussion. Let f(x,y)= $ \lbrace \frac{x}{y} \rbrace \lbrace \frac{y}{x} \rbrace$. Then 
  
  $$ \int_{x = a}^b \int_{y = a}^b  f(x,y)dxdy = \int_{x = 0}^b \int_{y = 0}^b  f(x,y)dxdy$$  
  $$  -  \int_{x = 0}^a \int_{y = 0}^a  f(x,y)dxdy - 2   \int_{x = 0}^b \int_{y = 0}^a  f(x,y)dxdy$$ 
  
  I get stuck trying to follow the idea used in calculus of the integrals on the squares  (0,a)$^2$ and (0,b)$^2$ in calculus of the last one.  Even taking b = 2a was not useful.

Comment: @user930740 There is no need for any approximation. The integral can be calculated exactly without much complication. I have edited your comment explaining what you have tried into the question body.

Answer (score 1):

Split the region $R=(a,b)^2$ into two: $R_1:=\{(x,y)\in R:x>y\},R_2:=\{(x,y)\in R:x<y\}$.

- In $R_1,0\le y/x<1$ so $\{ y/x\}=y/x$. But $1<x/y<b/a<2$, so $\{x/y\}=x/y-1$. Thus,

$$\begin{align*}I_{R_1}&=\int_{x = a}^b \int_{y = a}^x \frac yx\left(\frac xy-1\right)~dy~dx\\&
=\int_{x = a}^b \int_{y = a}^x\left(1-\frac yx\right)~dy~dx\\&
=\frac{b^2+3a^2-4ab}4+\frac{a^2}2\ln\left(\frac ba\right)
\end{align*}$$

- In $R_2,0\le x/y<1$ so $\{ x/y\}=x/y$. But $1<y/x<b/a<2$, so $\{y/x\}=y/x-1$. Thus,

$$I_{R_2}=\int_{y=a}^b \int_{x = a}^y \frac xy\left(\frac yx-1\right)~dx~dy=I_{R_1}$$Thus $I=I_{R_1}+I_{R_2}=\frac{b^2+3a^2-4ab}2+a^2\ln\left(\frac ba\right)$.